# Extract List<A> from List<Tuple<A,B>> without creating a copy?

Tags: c#, linq, reference

Short version: I know that C# works mostly, using references but I was wondering if that's also the case if you try to extract a `List<A>` from a `List<Tuple<A,B>>` while leaving the original List intact.

Long version: I am working with a lot of data right now, which means I need to be especially careful not to accidentally create a hardcopy of my data. I wrote a method which returns a `List<Tuple<A, List<B>>`. Each B is supposed to reference one A (not the one that it is already connected to through the Tuple). I can find the right object in `List<A>` using the information already contained in each B, however I obviously can't duplicate the Data in A or my RAM might explode. If I execute a command on the IEnumerable that is returned when I use `ListOfTuples.Select(x=>x.Item1);` will that operate on the `List<A>` in my `List<Tuple...>` or on a hardcopy?

Comment: `If I execute a command on the IEnumerable that is returned when I use ListOfTuples.Select(`.  Remember that LINQ uses deferred execution and the query will only be executed when it is enumerated for example in a `foreach` loop or after calling of `.ToList`

Comment: Question: What **exactly** do you mean by "without creating a copy"? I ask because that is prominently displayed in the title of your question yet you have commented "Awesome" on an answer that ... creates a copy. Also, I doubt that your usage of the word "hardcopy" means what you think it does. Hardcopy means a printed copy of your whatever. Can you please try to clear up what exactly you mean by "copy" here? What specifically is it that you don't want to make a copy of?

Comment: Maybe you should consider unsafe code and pointers if your ram is very limited. Do you write some embedded code?

Comment: Write your own IList<Tuple<A,B>> which has List<A> and List<B> inside it, and in the indexer, return a Tuple<A,B>. (If you insist on using tuples).

Comment: How do you want to use the extracted "list"? Do you need access it via an index, or do you just need to use it with `foreach`?

Answer (score 1):

If you can change your consuming code to use an `IReadOnlyList<T>` rather than a `List<T>` then it isn't too hard to write a class that converts a `Tuple<T,U>` to an `IReadOnlyList<T>`:

```
public sealed class TupleExtraction<T, U> : IReadOnlyList<T>
{
    readonly List<Tuple<T, U>> _list;

    public TupleExtraction(List<Tuple<T, U>> list)
    {
        _list = list;
    }

    public T this[int index] => _list[index].Item1;

    public int Count => _list.Count;

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.Select(item => item.Item1).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.Select(item => item.Item1).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

You could then use this like so:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<Tuple<string, int>> test = new List<Tuple<string, int>>
        {
            new Tuple<string, int>("one",   1),
            new Tuple<string, int>("two",   2),
            new Tuple<string, int>("three", 3)
        };

        var extract = new TupleExtraction<string, int>(test);

        for (int i = 0; i < extract.Count; ++i)
            Console.WriteLine(extract[i]);

        foreach (var item in extract)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Note that this doesn't make a copy of the underlying list.

Comment: What exactly does this achieve over `test.Select(x => x.Item1)` ? That's lazy eval too. And doesn't rely on IList.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It gives you an indexer? If the consuming code needs an indexer, then the Select won't help. (Although from the look of it, the OP might not need an indexer...)

Comment: Feature creep. The question specifically talks about getting an `IEnumerable<A>`

Comment: @HenkHolterman The question's title says `Extract List<A> from List<Tuple<A,B>> without creating a copy?`, so I was addressing that. I assumed that he wanted some kind of indexer, but perhaps he doesn't. OP will have to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<A> result = ListOfTuples.Select(x=>x.Item1).ToList()
```

When A is a reference type, it creates a second list of A without copying the A elements.
When A is a value type, it creates a second list containing a copy of the A elements

Comment: Awesome, gotta love C#!

Comment: Quite false... `List<Tuple<Guid, int>>` for example... And even a `List<Tuple<object, object>>` you are still copying the references. The operation is O(N) in time and space.

Comment: This answer completely misses the difference between structs and refs, so is partially untrue.

Comment: Yes you are right I wrongly assumed that A was a reference type